# Define macro using _Generic gives typename not allowed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, typename, visual-studio-macros

I am trying to define a generic macro, which I intend to use with exception handling while debugging the code. When I try to compile the code below, it says `typename not allowed.`
I am a noob when it comes to the macros, any and all help is highly appreciated.

```
#define ASSERTEXCP(x) _Generic((x),\
char *: printf( "assertion error line %d, file(%s):-> %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__, x );
char strMsg[2014] = {'\0'}; \
sprintf(strMsg, "\nassertion error line %d, file(%s):-> %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__, x); \
OutputDebugString(strMsg););


#endif
```

Comment: `_Generic` is C (C11), not C++. Different language

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic

It does work in C++ too.

Comment: @QasimShafi where in that page does it say that it works on C++ too?

Comment: try this one. working fine in C++11 & 14 http://cpp.sh/75hnig

Comment: I know _Generic is C, and for current instance i am unable to use it with C++ somehow, any suggestions about how I can achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: @QasimShafi Your link does not use _Generic. Try this one http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c11154ed84255ce

Comment: MS is doing something like this _GENERIC_MATH1(cbrt, _CRTSPECIAL). with extern C syntax.

Comment: `_Generic` is the C approach to C++ overloading. Perhaps use overloading or `if constexpr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_Generic` is the C approach to C++ overloading. C++ approach is to use `if constexpr` or an overloaded function:

```
    #include <type_traits>

    #define ASSERTEXCP(x) if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(x), char *>::value) {  \
    printf( "assertion error line %d, file(%s):-> %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__, x ); \
    char strMsg[2014] = {'\0'}; \
    sprintf(strMsg, "\nassertion error line %d, file(%s):-> %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__, x); \
    OutputDebugString(strMsg); }
```